# How does `do` ... `end` statement work without a block parameter?

Tags: ruby, codeblocks, local-variables

For example, in a Rails gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

what is going on with the `do` ... `end` statement? And with rspec:

```
describe "Foo" do
  context "bar" do
     expect...
  end
end
```

are the `do` ... `end`-s creating a block whose information in between is being used elsewhere? How is this working without setting a block parameter?

Comment: A simple, but common, example of the use of a block without block variables is initializing a two-dimensional array: `Array.new 5 do; []; end #=>  [[], [], [], [], []]`. You could write `do |i| []; end `, but Ruby doesn't mind if you drop the block variable if you don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

This is called Domain-Specific Language

> A Domain-Specific Language, or DSL, is “a programming language of limited expressiveness focused on a particular domain”. It makes tasks in its domain easier by removing extraneous code for a particular task and allowing you to focus on the specific task at hand. It also helps other people read the code, because the purpose of the code is so clear.

Basically this

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

is just a call of the method `group` with arguments `:development, :test` and with a block `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'`. [Which is defined in this way in Bundler DSL](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/carlhuda/bundler/Bundler/Dsl#group-instance_method):

```
def group(*args, &blk)
  ...
end
```

Same for your second example.

> DSL defines methods to group examples, most notably describe, and exposes them as class methods of RSpec.

[`.describe` is being implemented in this way](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup#describe-class_method):

```
def describe(doc_string, *metadata_keys, metadata = {}, &example_implementation)
  ...
end
```

You can read more about writing Domain-Specific Language in Ruby [in this thoughtbot.com article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I've read this twice and will probably need to go over it a few more times, but great resources! ++

Answer (score 2):

Receiving a block parameter is optional. If you are not using block variables, you don't have to write `|...|` even if the block is called with block variables.

```
def foo &block
  block.call(:foo)
end

foo{|v| puts "I received `:foo', but am not using it."}
foo{puts "I am called with `:foo', but am not receiving it."}
```

And also if the method is defined not to pass any block variable, then you don't need `|...|` in the block.

```
def bar &block
  block.call
end

bar{puts "I am not called with a block variable in the first place."}
```